# Flutter Multiple Blocs and NamedRoutes

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

Looking for a bit of advice regarding some flutter architecture. I'm building an app that has about 10 screens all stored as named routes and using onGenerateRoute.

I'm trying to implement blocs and streams so that I can broadcast to one page when another page, say, creates a new record (all handled in an online SQL db).

So I have two pages that use one bloc, another 3 pages that need access to another bloc... etc.. Does this mean that only way to provide access is to put a bloc provider for all blocs at the top of the widget tree, making all blocs available to all pages?

I tried to provide access to one bloc individually on two pages by using a provider at the top of each of those two pages... however, I guess this means I am actually creating two separate BloC objects? rather than both pages actually using the same one. So when page B creates a new record, it is not calling page A to reload...

I'd rather not have all pages accessing all BloCs, but is the only way to do it to put the Bloc in a place where it is a single ancestor of any page that needs it?

I'm also rather confused about why we close streams... I thought the point is that they are a continuous source of data... if we close them, are they no longer available to broadcast to subscribers?

Utterly confused, and 3 hours of YouTube videos later, I'm no clearer.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutterblocaccess?id=generated-route-access

When the Widgets that need the blocs are disposed, the blocs are also should be disposed. Otherwise you're consuming resources unnecessarily by keeping it alive.