# Flutter Streambuilder snapshot is null after moving to OnGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, bloc

Back again. I refactored my code after the advice in this thread: [Flutter Multiple Blocs and NamedRoutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060354/flutter-multiple-blocs-and-namedroutes/61060549#61060549)

However, since moving my bloc from the main material app tree to the router page, the data isn't loading as snapshot is null.

The Router:

```
class AppRouter {
  final _centresBloc = CentresBloc();

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {

    switch (settings.name) {
      case routes.CentreSelectScreenRoute:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
            bloc: _centresBloc,
            child: CentreSelectScreen(),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
    }
```

and the CentreSelectScreen class itself

```
class _CentreSelectScreenState extends State<CentreSelectScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _centresBloc = BlocProvider.of<CentresBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<ClimbingCentre>>(
            stream: _centresBloc.centres,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print('snapshot == ${snapshot.data}'); //is always null now
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // If there are no centres (data), display this message.
                if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Text('No Centres listed');
                }...
```

The blocprovider was originally in the centreselect screen class which all worked fine, but since moving it, it's not working, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Th blog itself seems to initialise properly when the app first loads, as it is printing out all the correct information. From CentresBloc:

```
  void getCentres() async {
    // Retrieve all the centres from the database
    List<ClimbingCentre> centres = await ClimbDB.db.getCentres();
    // Add all of the centres to the stream so we can grab them later from our pages
    _inCentres.add(centres);
    print('BLOC incentres is $centres'); //this works and prints all centres when the app first loads... 
  }
```

Any help most appreciated.

**EDIT** Adding CentresBloc Class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutterapp/data/database.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/models/centre_model.dart';
import 'bloc_provider.dart';

class CentresBloc implements BlocBase {

  final _centresController = StreamController<List<ClimbingCentre>>.broadcast();

  // Input stream. Add centres to the stream using this variable.
  StreamSink<List<ClimbingCentre>> get _inCentres => _centresController.sink;

  // Output stream. This one will be used within our pages to display the centres.
  Stream<List<ClimbingCentre>> get centres => _centresController.stream;

  CentresBloc() {
    // Retrieve all the climbing centres on initialization
    getCentres();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _centresController.close();
  }

  void getCentres() async {
    // Retrieve all the centres from the database
    List<ClimbingCentre> centres = await ClimbDB.db.getCentres();
    // Add all of the centres to the stream so we can grab them later from our pages
    _inCentres.add(centres);
    print('CentreBloc _incentres is: $centres'); //this prints the correct centres when the app is first loaded
  }
```

Comment: Please, show `CentresBloc` class

Comment: Thanks @IgorKharakhordin, I have added CentresBloc to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a new route is pushed, *StreamBuilder* subscribes to the same stream `_centresBloc.centres`, but no new events are emitted on this stream, as it only happens once - during bloc's initialization in constructor. That's because Dart's default *StreamController* won't send previous events/values (including the last one) to stream's new subscribers.

However, you can use [BehaviorSubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html) from [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) library, which is based on `StreamController`, but it also stores the last value emitted and sends it to any new subscriber. Subjects are also always broadcast streams and can have initial (seed) value.

Just replace this:

```dart
final _centresController = StreamController<List<ClimbingCentre>>.broadcast();
```

with this:

```
final _centresController = BehaviorSubject<List<ClimbingCentre>>();
```

Full working code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc_provider/bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp2());

class CentresBloc implements Bloc {
  final _centresController = BehaviorSubject<List<String>>();

  // Input stream. Add centres to the stream using this variable.
  StreamSink<List<String>> get _inCentres => _centresController.sink;

  // Output stream. This one will be used within our pages to display the centres.
  Stream<List<String>> get centres => _centresController.stream;

  CentresBloc() {
    // Retrieve all the climbing centres on initialization
    getCentres();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _centresController.close();
  }

  void getCentres() async {
    // Retrieve all the centres from the database
    List<String> centres = ['LIST'];
    // Add all of the centres to the stream so we can grab them later from our pages
    _inCentres.add(centres);
    print('CentreBloc _incentres is: $centres'); //this prints the correct centres when the app is first loaded
  }
}

class AppRouter {
  final _centresBloc = CentresBloc();

  Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {

    switch (settings.name) {
      case 'test':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider<CentresBloc>.fromBloc(
            bloc: _centresBloc,
            child: CentreSelectScreen(),
          ),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _centresBloc.dispose();
  }
}

class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApp2State createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {
  final _router = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: _router.generateRoute,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _router.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CentreSelectScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CentreSelectScreenState();
}

class _CentreSelectScreenState extends State<CentreSelectScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _centresBloc = BlocProvider.of<CentresBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text('push index'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                  },
                ),
                StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
                    stream: _centresBloc.centres,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      print('snapshot == ${snapshot.data}'); //is always null now
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        // If there are no centres (data), display this message.
                        if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                          return Text('No Centres listed');
                        } else {
                          return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                        }
                      }

                      return Container();
                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'test'),
            child: Text('push test')
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, snapshot is still returning null. :/

Comment: @GaryFrewin Other than that, your code looks fine. I've tested it with Subject and it works. Please, take a look at my updated answer with full code. For the sake of simplicity, I changed `ClimbingCentre` type to `String` and used `bloc_provider` library.

Comment: I had my own bloc_provider class rather than using the library. Once I switched over to the library everything started working. :) thanks.